# Normalization problems - how to normalize in case of set of points while new points arriving

Tags: clustering, normalization

I'm having a procedure in which I perform clustering, and later, for each new example I test if that example belongs to some of existing clusters, by calculating distance to existing centroids.

To avoid parameters being "boosted" I perform normalization while clustering, that is, I find the maximal value in the training set for the parameter and divide each measurement with that value.

The problem is, how should I perform normalization for new measurements?

I may have a value for parameter that is greater than maximal in the set used for clustering and in that way I can have problem while deciding does a measurement belong to a cluster or not and parameters may influence differently on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like z-score normalization.

Wait for enough data to be able to estimate the mean and variance with reasonable precision. Then **fix** these values and just use them from now on.

There is no rule that says the normalization parameters must be *exact*. All normalization is just a **crude heuristic** anyway, it won't get much worse (it may even get better sometimes) if you don't use all data for it.

Comment: +1 It should be stressed that once the normalization parameters are fixed, the same should be used for all the points and different points are not normalized with different parameters. Once I was horrified to find out a code where the train and test data were normalized with parameters computed from respective set ^_-

Comment: Or almost as bad: deriving the normalization from the full data set, then applying it to train and test sets - this can cause overfitting, because the normalization contains information on the extreme values. In such cases, normalization factors should be derived from the training data only, then the same parameters applied to the test set as well.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thank you for your answer, and thank you both for your comments. Sorry if I have formed my question poorly, but I need to perform normalization in order to do feature scaling, so all parameters could be on the same scale, which I need in case I want to use clustering, and then perform scaling in the same manner on the new arrived data. Can you explain to me why is this approach better than just dividing by maximum of the set?

Comment: Whether you need scaling for clustering or not depends a lot on the algorithm you are using, and the distance function. Z-score standardization is a best practise from statistics. **The maximum is much more sensitive to outliers**, obviously. The z-score is more robust. MAD may be a good choice; it should be even more robust; but if you have too many duplicates it could be 0.